# Cancel a cell value in a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

How can I delete a value from a cell in a `QTableView`?
I created a `QTableView` but if I press the cancel button of the keyboard on the selected cell nothing happens.
If I want to delete that value I have to double-click the cell and press cancel but I want to delete the value without the double-click, just selecting the cell and press `Canc`.

Is `keyEvent->key()` useful?

```
 @Chernobyl

    MAINWINDOW.H

    #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
    #define MAINWINDOW_H

    #include <QMainWindow>
    #include <QKeyEvent>
    #include <QTableView>

    namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
    }

    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0) ;
        ~MainWindow();
        QTableView *griglia;

    protected:
        bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);

    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;


    };

    #endif // MAINWINDOW_H





    MAINWINDOW.CPP

    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include "ui_mainwindow.h"

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent),ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        qApp->installEventFilter(this);
    }


    bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
    {
        if(obj == griglia && event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
        {
            QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
            if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Cancel)
            {
               QModelIndex in =griglia->currentIndex();
               griglia->model()->setData(in," ");
            }
        }
        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }

    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
        delete ui;
    }




MAIN.CPP



#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "itemdelegate.h"
#include "mymodel.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QFile>
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QIdentityProxyModel>
#include <QRegExpValidator>

#define GRIGLIA_RX "^[F0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4]$"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFile styleFile( "style.qss" );
    styleFile.open( QFile::ReadOnly );
    QString style( styleFile.readAll() );
    a.setStyleSheet( style );

    QWidget *mainWindow = new QWidget;    
    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(48,33);  
    QTableView *griglia = new QTableView;
    griglia->setModel(model);

    QPushButton *calcola = new QPushButton;
    calcola->setText("CALCOLA");

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(griglia);
    layout->addWidget(calcola);
    mainWindow->setLayout(layout);


    ItemDelegate *itDelegate = new  ItemDelegate;
    griglia->setItemDelegate(itDelegate);
    mainWindow->showMaximized();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I added QDebug line but if I press Canc no message appears

Comment: Ok, I think I found mistake, your eventfilter works only with griglia which located in mainwindow, not main.cpp, so you can see normal tableview but eventfilter doesn't work. Your current code will never work, you should do all your stuff inside mainwindow. I don't want compile it on my computer because it is a lot of work so I will write code which works in myBrain-compiler :) I will add code after few minutes

Comment: Check my edit, tell in  comment results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use next event filter as in my example or reimplement `keyPressEvent`:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if(obj == ui->tableView && event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
        if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Shift)
        {
           qDebug() << "works";
           QModelIndex in =  ui->tableView->currentIndex();
           ui->tableView->model()->setData(in,"");
           //ui->tableView->model()->setData(ui->tableView->currentIndex(),""); //or just this

        }
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

To use `eventFilter` you should also:

```
protected:
bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);//in header
```

and

```
qApp->installEventFilter(this);//in constructor
```

You can use `Qt::Key_Shift` or `Qt::Key_Cancel` or something else.

EDIT

```
MAINWINDOW.H

    #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
    #define MAINWINDOW_H

    #include <QMainWindow>
    #include <QKeyEvent>
    #include <QTableView>
    #include "itemdelegate.h"
#include "mymodel.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QFile>
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QIdentityProxyModel>
#include <QRegExpValidator>

    namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
    }

    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0) ;
        ~MainWindow();
        QTableView *griglia;

    protected:
        bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);

    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;


    };

    #endif // MAINWINDOW_H





    MAINWINDOW.CPP

    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include "ui_mainwindow.h"


    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent),ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
            QWidget *mainWindow = new QWidget;    
    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(48,33);  
    griglia = new QTableView;
    griglia->setModel(model);

    QPushButton *calcola = new QPushButton;
    calcola->setText("CALCOLA");

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(griglia);
    layout->addWidget(calcola);
    mainWindow->setLayout(layout);


    ItemDelegate *itDelegate = new  ItemDelegate;
    griglia->setItemDelegate(itDelegate);

    this->setCentralWidget(mainWindow);
        qApp->installEventFilter(this);
    }


    bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
    {
        if(obj == griglia && event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
        {
            QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
            if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Cancel)
            {
               QModelIndex in =griglia->currentIndex();
               griglia->model()->setData(in," ");
            }
        }
        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }

    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
        delete ui;
    }




MAIN.CPP



#include "mainwindow.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFile styleFile( "style.qss" );
    styleFile.open( QFile::ReadOnly );
    QString style( styleFile.readAll() );
    a.setStyleSheet( style );

    MainWindow my;
    my.showMaximized();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Now you should see "works" and cell should be cleared, another code optimization do by yourself.

Addition for multiple selection:

```
if(obj == ui->tableView && event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
{
    QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
    if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Shift)
    {
        qDebug() << "Up";
       //ui->tableView->model()->setData(ui->tableView->currentIndex(),"");
       QList<QModelIndex> index = ui->tableView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
       for(int i = 0; i < index.size(); i++)
           ui->tableView->model()->setData(index.at(i),"");
    }
}
```

Comment: No errors, no warnings but it doesn't work. I think i'm doing something wrong. 
Do I have to write "nameofmyQTableView->installEventFilter(this);"?

Comment: @Aimcorz No, it should be qApp, post your code, maybe I will find mistake because my example perfectly works on my computer.

Comment: @Aimcorz I saw code, first of all, on SO will be better if you just edit your question and add full code in question, you should not create code as answer. I can't see mistakes here, so I hope that you allocate memory to qtableview but just didn't show it in code, yes? And second: there is `qDebug() << "works";` in my answer, add this line too and tell me is you can see this word when press cancel button, also try this with shift button. Tell me results.

Comment: Thank you, now it works! I replaced Qt::Key_Cancel with Qt::Key_Delete.
Can you give me an advice to cancel cells with multiple selection in this way?

Comment: @Aimcorz I will think how it can be done in easy way

Comment: @Aimcorz Thank you, I found efficient way, but accordingly to SO rules again you should ask one question, but I think that it will good if you will not create new question about multiple selection, so I just posted answer to your question. Check it please